# Angular: Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a few components with code like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    import('../aside-chat/aside-chat-boxes').then((_)=>{
    this.chatboxManager = _.chatboxManager
    })
}
```

As you can see it's importing some js scripts in the `ngOnInit` method.

It was working on Angular 7, now I upgraded my project to Angular 8 and it stopped working with the following error:

> ERROR in
>   ./src/app/shared/chat/aside-chat-user/aside-chat-user.component.ts
>   21:8 Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the
>   top level (21:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this
>   file type. |     AsideChatUserComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function
>   () { |         var *this = this;
>            import('../aside-chat/aside-chat-boxes').then(function (*) { |             _this.chatboxManager = _.chatboxManager; |         });

I found some questions here at StackOverflow regarding this error, but they are all related to webpack, and in an Angular CLI project I can't see or edit the webpack configuration.

Is there any way to solve this without going back to Angular 7? Or another way of writing this code?

Comment: It uses, but it's hide inside its inner workings, it doesn't expose it to the user.